# AnkhSVN is not getting referenced dll when getting latest version

Tags: ankhsvn

A colleague modified a Visual Studio 2010 solution to include a Libs folder that includes the Moq dll. He commited his modifications to SVN using TortoiseSVN.

I have AnkhSVN version 2.3.11269 installed which has been working fine until now. When I tried to update the solution to the latest version the Libs folder shows up in Solution Explorer but the Moq.dll file within it has a blue question mark next to it, the testing project displays a warning sign next to the Moq reference and neither the dll nor the folder has been downloaded to my local file system.

Has anyone have this problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Updating at the project level only update the directory containing the project. Try updating at the solution level to get all changes.

If you already did that:

Make sure the Moq dll is in the same working copy as the rest of the solution. If it is, go to File - Subversion - Change Source Control to correct the value of the solution root. This root is updated when you update at the solution level.